# Calling AndroidJni static method with string parameter

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qtandroidextras

I am trying to call a Java static function in Qt C++ class using QAndroidJniObject with a string parameter.

This is my Java class having function which i am calling

```
        public class StatusBar{

        public static void setStatusBarBackgroundColor(Activity activity,String colorPref) {

// My code


         }  
        }
```

I am calling this function from C++ as

```
void ECApplicationInfo::changeStatusBarColor(QString color)
{
  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>( 
                  "com/ezeecube/ezeesync/StatusBar",
                  "setStatusBarBackgroundColor",
                  "(Landroid/app/Activity;)V",
                   activity,color);
}
```

I am getting the following error

> error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class
>   QString' through '...'
>                       activity,color);

How can i get rid of this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of your function signature is not correct. You should also specify the second argument which has a type of `Ljava/lang/String;`. Also you should convert `QString` to `jstring` and the pass it as an argument :

```
QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>( 
                  "com/ezeecube/ezeesync/StatusBar",
                  "setStatusBarBackgroundColor",
                  "(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                   activity,QAndroidJniObject::fromString(color).object<jstring>());
```

Comment: Can i change orientation of android screen if it is fixed in androidManifest

Comment: I dont get any error but the function is also not getting called

Comment: I don't know how you are providing `activity` parameter. May be that's the problem.

Comment: @Nejat can you please help with This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289447/saving-qtime-in-sql-server-an-retrieve-back

Answer (score 2):

JNI doesn't understand `QString`, you need to convert it to JNI's `jstring` type. `QAndroidJniObject` has a handy static method for this:

```
QString q = "Hello world";
QAndroidJniObject jniObject = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(q);
jstring j = jniObject.object<jstring>();
```

This is fairly typical, JNI bridges generally require manual serialization between types.

`QAndroidJniObject` also provides a [toString() method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#toString) for converting from a Java string back to a `QString`.