# How to save QTime in SQL Server Express table and read it back?

Tags: c++, qt, sql-server-express

I have a table in SQL Server Express with fields `name varchar(10)` and `timeVar time` and I want to save the value of a `QTime` variable in the `time` field.

This is what I have tried:

```
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
QString timeString = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
QString query = QString("insert into timeHold(name,timeVar) values ('ABC','%2')").arg(timeString);

qry->prepare(query);
qry->exec();
```

However, I get `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record`.

When I insert values into the table from SQL Server Management Studio, `insert into timeHold values('XYZ', '12:17:35')` works perfectly. To my surprise though, when I have tried reading the values stored in the table from the management studio, I was able to get the name field, but not time field.

Here is the code I use to read values from the table:

```
QString query = QString("select * from timeHold");

qry->prepare(query);
qry->exec();
qry->first();

int noOfRecords = qry->numRowsAffected();

do {
    qDebug() << qry->value(0).toString();
    qDebug() << qry->value(1).toString();
} while (qry->next());
```

The code produces the following output:

```
"ABC"
"\u0017"
"world"
"\u000B"
"Mama"
"\u000B"
"Gerama"
"\u000B"
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Could you complete your question with the actual output from slq-server describing the table you have  (exec sp_columns timeHold) ?

Comment: Did you try `qry->value(1).toTime().toString("hh:mm:ss");`? Also, as was mentioned before, it'll be helpful if we could see your SQL table structure.

Answer (score 5):

For the saving story , I would say  the arg method does not work because you ask for %2 but there is only one element to substitute

```
   query = QString("insert into timeHold(name,timeVar) values ('ABC','%2')").arg(timeString);
```

I think it should be

```
query =  QString("insert into timeHold(name,timeVar) values ('ABC','%1')").arg(timeString);
```

For retrieving from the DB, it's either because you have to specify the format when inserting or when reading